# Handling button state and actions in redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to react and redux.

Overview of app: I have a ToggleButtonGroup with two buttons. When a button is click I want to output a table for the respective button. The tables we filtered based on the button click.

Question: I am not sure how to setup an action, state and reducer in my project for the button functionality. My button is a component. Is it best practice to use actions and reducers for buttons? How would I pass these actions to other components? Any examples or resources is appreciated.

This is my Button.tsx file

```
import React, { Component, useState  } from 'react'
import ToggleButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup';
import ToggleButton  from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButton';



function ToggleButtonGroupControlled() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([1, 2]);

    return (
      <ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={() => setValue(value)}>
        <ToggleButton value={1}>PA Probes</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={2}>Convential Probes</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    );
  }


export class Buttons extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ToggleButtonGroupControlled />  
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Buttons
```

This is my types.ts file

```
export const TOGGLE_PA_PROBES = 'TOGGLE_PA_PROBES';
export const TOGGLE_CONVENTIONAL_PROBES = 'TOGGLE_CONVENTIONAL_PROBES';
```

This is buttonAction.ts file

```
import{ TOGGLE_PA_PROBES, TOGGLE_CONVENTIONAL_PROBES } from './types';

export function togglePAProebs(){

}

export function toggleConventionalProbes(){
}
```

This is my buttonReducers.ts file

```
import{ TOGGLE_PA_PROBES, TOGGLE_CONVENTIONAL_PROBES } from '../Actions/types';


export function ButtonReducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you know the basics of redux and react-redux. In short, you know that an action is dispatched to a store.

In a real world situation, it is as if you change a channel on your TV, (1) you dispatch a CHANGE_CHANNEL action to your remote control, (2) the remote control will receive the action dispatched and send that action with the channel information to your TV (reducer), then (3) your TV (reducer) will talk to your cable provider (store), and return the channel data back if it is available to you.

That flow is important because it can be used in your example as well. To begin with, imagine you have a store with some probes. On toggling your checkbox, you will dispatch an action FILTER, which will filter out the probes that need to be shown from a database list, for example, then call your reducer with the filtered probes to update your store and send that data back to your dispatcher.

When you first load your page, I also imagine you want to show the list of all your probes, so you would also need a FETCH action to be dispatched upon componentDidMount. Having that in mind, we can come up with a types file like this:

types.js

```
export const TOGGLE_PROBES = "TOGGLE_PROBES"; 
export const LOAD_PROBES = "LOAD_PROBES";
```

Now that the types are defined, we can create our actions,

```js
import { TOGGLE_PROBES, LOAD_PROBES } from "./types";

const dbProbes = [
  { title: "pa probe 1", type: 1 },

  { title: "pa probe 2", type: 1 },

  { title: "conditional probe 1", type: 2 },

  { title: "conditional probe 1", type: 2 }
];

function toggleProbes(filtered) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_PROBES,
    filtered: filtered
  };
}

function loadProbes(probes) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_PROBES,
    probes: probes
  };
}

export function fetchProbes() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(loadProbes(dbProbes));
  };
}

export function filterProbes(filter) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const filtered = dbProbes.filter(probe => filter.includes(probe.type));
    dispatch(toggleProbes(filtered));
  };
}
```

Notice that I created a fake list of probes called dbProbes. In a real world situation, you would probably be reaching out to a database to filter your probes.

After having all of the actions set up, you can finally work on the reducer and update your state accordingly,

```js
import { TOGGLE_PROBES, LOAD_PROBES } from "./types";

const initialState = {
  probes: []
};

function ButtonReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_PROBES:
      return { ...state, probes: action.filtered };
    case LOAD_PROBES:
      return { ...state, probes: action.probes };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default ButtonReducer;
```

In order to be able to dispatch this in your components, you do need to set redux up. In your index.js, you could accomplish that by using both react, react-redux and react-thunk. React-thunk is a middleware which is often used with redux for async calls.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "./styles.css";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Buttons />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

First, in your Button components, maybe you just want to show the initial list first, so to do that you need to use a react-redux high order component called connect, which will, as the name states, connect your store and map your store's state to dispatchers and props.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ToggleButtonGroupControlled from "./ToggleButtonGroupControlled";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProbes } from "./store/action";

export class Buttons extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProbes();
  }

  render() {
    let probes = null;

    if (this.props.probes) {
      probes = this.props.probes.map(probe => <li>{probe.title}</li>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleButtonGroupControlled />
        <ul>{probes}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    probes: state.probes
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchProbes: () => dispatch(fetchProbes())
  };
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Buttons);
```

Finally, your toggle button component can properly dispatch a TOGGLE_FILTER action to your actions.js, which will filter the probes, then send the action to reducer, which will update your state and return the updated state, which at this point is mapped to your component props in your Button.js component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ToggleButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ToggleButton } from "react-bootstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { filterProbes } from "./store/action";

function ToggleButtonGroupControlled(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([1, 2]);

  const toggleChangeHandler = newValue => {
    setValue(newValue);
    props.filterProbes(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      type="checkbox"
      value={value}
      onChange={e => toggleChangeHandler(e)}
    >
      <ToggleButton value={1}>PA Probes</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={2}>Convential Probes</ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    filterProbes: types => dispatch(filterProbes(types))
  };
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ToggleButtonGroupControlled);
```

The cool thing about redux is that it allows for a global state, so you dispatch and change your list of probes from the ToggleButtonGroupControlled component, but that store (list of probes) it's also available for other components that you decide to connect to your store, in this case, Button.js.

You can check the final code running and ready for your problem here:

[image: Edit sad-dirac-w21w5]

To understand more about redux-thunk, go here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Also, there's a free redux book here that you could maybe take a quick look at: https://leanpub.com/redux-book

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I will continue to practice and hopefully I can be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

Redux might be overkill for this example, it all depends however at what level in the component hierarchy your table lives in relation to your `ToggleButtonGroupControlled` component.
It would help in your question to see the table component,  is it in a separate file / route?

I would start simple and pass the value up out of your `ToggleButtonGroupControlled` component by creating  an `onChange` prop. Right now your `ToggleButtonGroupControlled` component doesn't add much more functionality
 than the third party `ToggleButtonGroup` component so it's a little hard to reason about.

Also if you do choose to go the redux route because you need this data in the global state then you can probably forego the local state you have here and select it from your redux store and pass into the component